# Setup ubuntu server to send mail()

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ubuntu

I tried searching a lot but unable to find how to actually setup a ubuntu server, so that I can send mails through php using mail() function in php.

I have apache2, mysql and php5 installed on my server.

Thank You.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I also agree there is a lack of tutorials for people who just need a script to send, e.g. error emails, and don't need a full-blown mail server.

First, if postfix not already installed do:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

It prompts with a couple of questions. For the first I chose "Internet site"; for a machine behind a firewall I might choose smarthost instead.
For the second question it defaults to the machine name; I appended a domain name that I control (so I can set DNS for it later, should I need to).

At this point you should be able to use "mail" from the commandline to send a test. (I usually follow instructions on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=38429 first, otherwise I have to use the `-f` flag to `/usr/bin/sendmail`. I also like to create `/etc/aliases` with entries for root and my normal user, and then run `newaliases`)

Then under /etc/php5/conf.d create a file (e.g. mailconfig.ini) with these contents:

```
sendmail_from = "me@example.com"
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f me@example.com"
```

Change me@example.com to your email address. They mean all email will look like it is sent by you, which can help prevent it being rejected. This is sufficient for just sending error emails to a developer.

(The above instructions tested on Ubuntu 10.04, 11.04, 11.10, 12.04)

P.S. As pointed out by razzed in the comments, `mail` is not always there (e.g. on Ubuntu 11.10 it is missing). This does not actually affect the above instructions, you only need `mail` for the test, and you can use `sendmail` just as well for that. But `mail` is also useful for reading email, so it is usually worth installing it, with: `apt-get install mailutils` (as root).

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64.

Comment: This resolves find using NGINX too! And PHP5-FPM

Comment: Note on my host, the `mail` command-line utility is not installed on a clean Ubuntu install, and installing PostFix does not install it. Try `sudo apt-get install mailutils` to get the `mail` command, or use alternatives such as Mutt, or `ssmtp`

Comment: I needed weeks to figure out that the stuff behinde `sendmail_path` has to be in `"` to work correctly, like `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f me@example.com"`

Comment: @Panique I don't have the quotes on my installations. The manual just says you "can" use quotes, not that you must. However they should do no harm, and maybe it matters on some PHP versions, so I just updated the answer to include them. Thanks.

Comment: Finally! A straight forward and simple solution. Works on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to setup the ubuntu server to be able to send mail ... as an example, you could install and configure postfix.

The Ubuntu documentation has a nice page at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer

Comment: any tutorial you can link me to?

Comment: added a tutorial link

Answer (score 1):

Either go through the painful process of setting up a mail server directly on your server (postfix, etc) or use a library that will allow you to connect directly to a smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install xmail package, and if it still does not work, have a look [over here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-262177.html).