# wordpress on nginx on ubuntu server doesn't send mail

Tags: nginx, postfix, sendmail, ubuntu-20.04

I want to send a mail with WordPress `wp_mail` function.
I've seen this topic:
[Setup ubuntu server to send mail()](https://serverfault.com/questions/119105/setup-ubuntu-server-to-send-mail/289290#289290)

and I've installed postfix, after installing postfix I get a successful message when I send mail but actually, the mail is not in my inbox.

I've installed mailutils and it doesn't solve the problem.

How can I enable PHP mail on Nginx?

thanks

Comment: what is the business relationship in here? this is a basic administrative task imho.  in my point of view it is a end user question that is not on topic for serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com

Comment: Please add the postfix configuration and relevant log entries from your mail log from your attempts to send mails to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I could be far off here, but on my little home server with my cable Internet Service Provider, email doesn't work because my ISP blocks direct outbound TCP/IP connections to port 25.